# Random Quiz with one answer

Tags: android

Can u help me with the code for randomizing the questions of a quiz in android studio ? I know the code for random but the problem is that i have answers too and i don't know how to connect with that .. Here is my code:

```
public class Questions {



public String mQuestions[]= {
        "Care este prima planeta?",
        "Cine a fost primul presedinte al SUA?",
        "In ce an a murit Adolf Hitler?",
        "De cate ori a iesit Michael Schumacher campion mondial al F1?",
        "La ce echipa a jucat Gica Popescu in Spania?"



};

private String mChoices[][]={
        {"Mercur","Venus","Pamant","Marte"},
        {"Abraham Lincoln","William H. Taft","George Washington","John F. Kennedy"},
        {"1940","1945","1944","1947"},
        {"3","2","4","7"},
        {"Barcelona","Real Madrid","Valencia","Espanyol"}


};
private String mCorrectAnswers[]={"Mercur","George Washington","1945","7","Barcelona"};

public String getQuestion(int a){
    String question = mQuestions[a];
    return question;
}

public String getChoice1(int a){
    String choice= mChoices [a][0];
    return choice;
}
public String getChoice2(int a){
    String choice= mChoices [a][1];
    return choice;
}
public String getChoice3(int a){
    String choice= mChoices [a][2];
    return choice;
}
public String getChoice4(int a){
    String choice= mChoices [a][3];
    return choice;
}
public String getCorrectAnswer(int a){
    String answer=mCorrectAnswers[a];
    return answer;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a class or struct Question like this:

```
class Question
{
  String   Question;
  String[] Choices;
  int      CorrectChoiceIndex;
}
```

That way, all related data is stored togehter, so if you create an array of Questions you can simply pick a valid random index.